# Adding force to an object (like a trampoline)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have objects that act like trampolines, and I have an object that when it falls on the trampoline it should be shot in the direction that the trampoline is facing (Up/Down/Left/Right/Angled etc.).

I have tried two things to try an accomplish this, and neither works. Here was my first attempt:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        other.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * 2500, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

And here was my second attempt:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        other.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles * 2500, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

What can I use to get the effect that I am looking for?

**EDIT**

Here is the full method if that helps at all:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        other.gameObject.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;

        other.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.forward * forceAmount, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(Color2.Rand(), Color2.Rand(), Color2.Rand(), 1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work about your two attempts? Also, if a trampoline is horizontal (180º) hitting it doesn't mean you'll shoot up at 90º as it's dependent on the angle of the object hitting the trampoline - not sure if that is being stated in your provided code but just wanted to give a heads up :)

Comment: Attempt 1 shoots everything straight up, and attempt 2 the Object just rolls around on top of the trampoline

Comment: Does the bounce velocity need to depend on the collision velocity? Like if the object hits it at 10, should it bounce off at 10? Or is it a fixed bounce velocity?

Comment: It is a fixed bounce, It can come in at any angle and should launch at a fixed direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bounce in direction trampoline is facing, in your first attempt instead of

```
other.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * 2500, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

use

```
other.gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.forward * 2500, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

If you want to have fixed force consider changing rigidbody2D.velocity directly.

Comment: transform.forward isn't working, it has the same effect as my second attempt

Comment: Is your trampoline's forward (blue axis) the direction you want? Is the model rotated in a weird direction?